# Testing form with CKEditor

Tags: symfony, ckeditor

I want to test my `ArticleForm` which contains `CKEditor` field:

```
$builder->add('content', CKEditorType::class, array(
    'config' => array('uiColor' => '#ffffff'),
    'required' => true));
```

However when I run `PHPUnit` I got the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType::__construct() 
must be an instance of Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Model\ConfigManagerInterface, none given
```

My **test** config is the same as for **dev** and **prod** where `CKEditor` works fine:

```
ivory_ck_editor:
    default_config: default
    configs:
        default:
            filebrowserBrowseRoute: elfinder
            filebrowserBrowseRouteParameters: []
```

The test case extends Symfonys' `TypeTestCase` which creates its' own factory. This probably is the cause. However I don't know how to force this factory to provide the proper CKEditor instance. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved with `PreloadedExtension`:

```
class ArticleTypeTest {

    protected function getExtensions() {
        return array(new PreloadedExtension(array($this->getCKEditor()), array()));
    }

    ...

    protected function getCKEditor() {
        $configManager = $this->getMockBuilder ( ConfigManagerInterface::class )->disableOriginalConstructor ()->getMock ();
        $pluginManager = $this->getMockBuilder ( PluginManagerInterface::class )->disableOriginalConstructor ()->getMock ();
        $stylesSetManager = $this->getMockBuilder ( StylesSetManagerInterface::class )->disableOriginalConstructor ()->getMock ();
        $templateManager = $this->getMockBuilder ( TemplateManagerInterface::class )->disableOriginalConstructor ()->getMock ();

        $type = new CKEditorType($configManager, $pluginManager, $stylesSetManager, $templateManager);

        return $type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! For latest versions of the Ivory CKEditor bundle, you will also need to mock the toolbar manager:

 `$toolbarManager = $this->getMockBuilder(ToolbarManagerInterface::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

$type = new CKEditorType($configManager, $pluginManager, $stylesSetManager, $templateManager, $toolbarManager);`